# Derivation of a function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x)=\log_{}|x|$, then $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ Why is that I don't apply rule for derivation of composition of functions(is this term correct in English?) $(f(g(x)))'=f'(g(x))g'(x)$. Since there is absolute value in logarithm, I would assume that derivation would be $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}sgn(x)$.
Thank you

Comment: Using the chain rule with $|x|$ as the "inner function", the derivative is $(1/|x|)\cdot\text{sgn}(x)$.

Comment: Which of course, is just $1/x$.

Comment: Oh I see now, so that means that they just cancel out? Thank you for answering, now it is clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Chain Rule says that if $f=g\circ h,$ and $x$ is such that $h$ is differentiable at $x$ and $g$ is differentiable at $h(x),$ then $$f'(x)=g'\bigl(h(x)\bigr)h'(x).$$

In this case, $f(x)=g\bigl(h(x)\bigr),$ where $g(x)=\ln x,$ $h(x)=|x|,$ $g'(x)=\frac1x,$ and $h'(x)=\operatorname{sgn}x.$ Bearing in mind that for all non-zero real $x$ we have $|x|=x\cdot\operatorname{sgn}x,$ it follows that $$\begin{align}f'(x) &= g'\bigl(h(x)\bigr)h'(x)\\ &= \frac1{|x|}\cdot\operatorname{sgn}x\\ &=\frac1{x\cdot\operatorname{sgn}x}\cdot \operatorname{sgn}x\\ &= \frac1x,\end{align}$$ as desired.

Comment: I only have one additional question that is rather linguistic, a function that is made of two or more elementary functions would be called composition of functions?

Comment: It depends on how it is "made" of those functions. For example, $|x|+\ln x$ is "made" of two more elementary functions, but it is not a composition of these two functions. The chain rule deals specifically with compositions of functions, if that's what you're asking.